# Where can I find the complete documentation on TDApiOle80.TDConnection library - Connection to ALM?

Tags: vbscript, alm

I am trying to connect to ALM and retrieve some info into MS Excel.

I see a lot of questions and examples on the web regarding this, but I can't find a documentation on this library.

Can someone please share the link to the documentation of this library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're logged in to ALM, there should be a menu Help->Documentation Library. There you find the HP ALM Open Test Architecture API Reference...